# Editing the Theme Customisation Menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Where is the file(s) that control the appearance of the Theme Customization Menu located?

The menu that I need to edit is found under Appearance > Themes > Customize, but where is the code (file name) that creates this menu usually located.?

Comment: You want to know the file name

Comment: Yes. the file name.

Comment: Since you didnt develop the theme, I will advice you check with the theme documentation if there's any. Depending on the developer's style of coding and/or file/folder structure, the menu could have been generated from any number of place: using a function file, a menu-related files and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your admin menu in an Array format check their files.

- For Appearance menu -  nav-menus.php
- For admin main menu-  menu.php

  All the files located into a wp-admin folder.

I think its help you check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to check wp-content/themes/your-theme/header.php

If you want to create or call menu in header then create child theme and create or copy header.php file from parent to  child theme and edit accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php